# In Rails how do I display javascript as text on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, interpolation, clipboard

I have a  [JS Fiddle](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/vNvEwE)

I want to interpolate a small javascript script as text on a rails .erb view.

i want to take the input element from the js fiddle and store the javascript string as the value of the input element so that I can use the fiddle to copy the script into the clipboard.

The catch is this... I want to be able to interpolate some values into the string. i.e.

```
"function() {var arr = [<%= @rails_value %>]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the code in which ruby data pass in js variable and add data to html page.

## filename.html.erb

```
<div class="test"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  add_text()

  function add_text(){
    var value = '<%= @rails_value %>'
    $(".test").html(value)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.